# Using a _GET gives me a debug error (over my head)

Tags: themes, urls, debug

Just looking for some advice on something that is bugging me. Please bear in mind I am a PHP noob :-)

I am passing a variable in the url to my WP index page like so:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/?do=thing">Thing</a>
```

I am the catching that variable, and using it to show content like so:

```
<?php $do_that = $_GET["do"]; if($do_that == 'thing') : ?> etc
```

Naturally I am getting debug errors when the variable is not passed :-)

```
"Undefined index: do"
```

My question is what am I missing wrong? Obvious I spose?

Also is this bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring as the $_GET array doesn't have the item $_GET['do'] in it. Therefore it throws this notice. To check if something exisits in the array try:

```
if( isset( $_GET['do'] ) )
   $do_that = $_GET['do'];
else
   $do_that = '';
```

or a cleaner method would be to use short hand notation

```
$do_that = ( isset( $_GET['do'] ) ) ? $_GET['do'] : '';
```

Comment: You will still need to validate the data, remember to NEVER trust a users input. Check out the article http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation there are some great helper functions that can clean the data :)